# Delete objects in an array for less then condition using Mongoose not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

To make it short, within my doc i have 1 property called weeks which is an Array containing Objects.

```
[
    {
        "time": [
            "06",
            "00"
        ],
        "active": false,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": 202102260600,
        "qdate": 20210226,
        "booked": false
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "06",
            "15"
        ],
        "active": false,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": 202102260615,
        "qdate": 20210226,
        "booked": false
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "06",
            "30"
        ],
        "active": false,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": 202102260630,
        "qdate": 20210226,
        "booked": false
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "06",
            "45"
        ],
        "active": false,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": 202102260645,
        "qdate": 20210226,
        "booked": false
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "07",
            "00"
        ],
        "active": false,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": 202103010700,
        "qdate": 20210301,
        "booked": false
    },
    {
        "time": [
            "07",
            "15"
        ],
        "active": false,
        "reason": "",
        "bookTime": 202103020715,
        "qdate": 20210302,
        "booked": false
    },
]
```

Now i want to delete all objects where the property is less then 20210302.

This query successfully deletes all occurences which have the property qdate: 20210226:

```
   const company = await Company.updateMany(
    { email: 'test@gmail.com' },
    { $pull: { weeks: { qdate: 20210226 } } }
  );
```

I tried to expand this query above to

```
 { $pull: { weeks: { qdate: {$lt:20210302 }} } }
```

So all values less then 20210302 should be deleted, but nada.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok i checked it again, my expanded query works

```
 const company = await Company.updateMany(
    { email: 'test@gmail.com' },
    { $pull: { weeks: { qdate: { $lt: 20210303 } } } }
  );
```

Dont know maybe i had a typo before